# c++ passing function itself as argument

Tags: c++

I have a containerclass that holds various objects in a map that have similar getter functions. That is itself contained in a class that uses that data. so, I have a bit of a chain here which seems not ideal.

```
class Obj {
    double getA() { return m_a; }
    double getB() { return m_b; }
    ....

    double m_a, m_b, ...;
}

class Container {
    map<long, Obj> m_objs;

    getA( int i ) { return m_objs[i].getA(); }
    getB( int i ) { return m_objs[i].getB(); }
}

class User {
    Conainer m_cont;
    getA( int i ) { return m_cont.getA( i ); }
```

Is there a more generic way to get the objects values by somehow passing the calling function into it. I admit the whole construct with the long chain doesnt seem ideal, but in that context it seems natural because I have some sort of tree of objects and carry information upwards to the top node and I would not know how to avoid this. But if there are any suggestions of a better way to deal with this, I am happy to hear it

Comment: The better way to deal with it is for the container to have a single `get()`, that returns the `Obj &`, and have the caller figure out which getter it wants to invoke on the returned object.

Comment: That seems like a pretty good start. thanks Sam

Comment: I think you could use the design pattern: Factory Pattern. This can help the user of your class to avoid the constructors with long chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you would need to pass in this scenario is a *pointer to member function*:

```
class Obj {
  // ...

  double getA() {
    return a;
  }

  double getB() {
    return b;
  }

private:
  double a;
  double b;
};

class Container {
  // ...
  get(int i, double (Obj::*what)()) { return (m_objs[i].*what)(); }
};

class User {
  Container m_cont;
  // ...
  get(int i, double (Obj::*what)()) { return m_cont.get(i, what); }
};

// ...
double myA = user.get(1, &Obj::getA);
```

You can also add this to `Obj`:

```
double get(double (Obj::*what)()) {
  return (this->*what)();
}
```

to make `Container` more consistent with `User`:

```
class Container {
  // ...
  get(int i, double (Obj::*what)()) { return m_objs[i].get(what); }
};
```